Pushing a convex cone and equidistants
Let $K$ be  a closed convex cone in an n-dimensional Euclidean space.
Suppose $K$ has  non-empty interior.  For $t > 0$
form  the subcone $K_t$   consisting of all points in $K$ which lie a distance $t$ or greater from the boundary of $K$.
True or False? $K_t$ is a translate of $K$.
In other words, can we obtain $K_t$ by pushing $K$ into its interior?
Motivation:  this problem arose while trying to establish
the ‘optimal worst-case escape rate’ from the collision locus
in the $N$-body problem. In the collinear equal mass $N$-body problem, the $N-1$ dimensional cone $K$  of interest is the one
defined by the inequalities $ x_1 \le  x_2 \le \dotsb \le x_N$
within the hyperplane $\sum x_i = 0$ of ${\mathbb R}^N$.
(You might call this the “$A_N$ cone” since it is a Weyl chamber for the $A_N$ Lie algebra.)
What do I know?
Not much beyond two dimensions and a lot of special cases.  In two dimensions the assertion is true.  $K$ is a sector. $K_t$ is the translate of $K$  by a vector directed along the bisector of the angle formed by the sector's boundary.  It follows that the   assertion also holds for  three-dimensional trihedral cones:  i.e. those $K$'s in 3-space whose  affine cross-section
is a triangle.   It seems a dissection + limit  argument ought
lead from here to the general 3-dimensional result but I did not get even this.
Convex geometry terminology?  If the assertion is true, then the length of the translation vector taking $K$ to  $K_1$  measures of the “sharpness” of the cone $K$. This length  is the reciprocal of $m(K)= \max_{q \in \operatorname{int}(K)} \operatorname{dist}(q, \partial K)/\|q\|$ as $q$ varies over the interior of $K$.   Does any one know the convex geometry term for this $m(K)$ or its reciprocal, the “sharpness” of $K$?

TeX note: the usual TeX command for sums is \sum, not \Sigma (compare $\Sigma x_i = 0$ \Sigma x_i = 0 to $\sum x_i = 0$ \sum x_i = 0).  MathJax note: backticks are parsed by the MathJax parser, not by TeX, so having too many of them in a paragraph can result in the intervening text being effectively wrapped in <pre>, as happened in this post.  It's better to use " " or “ ” on MO.  I edited accordingly for both.

$K_t$ need not be a translate of $K$. Let $A=[-4,4]\times[-1,1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the convex cone $K=\{t\cdot v;t\in[0,\infty),v\in A\times\{1\}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$. Note that $\partial K$ is contained in the union of the four planes $x_2=\pm x_3$ and $x_1=\pm4x_3$, so points in $K_1$ will be points of $K$ at distance $\geq1$ of those four planes.
Clearly $K$ has a unique point with minimal $x_3$ coordinate, the point $(0,0,0)$. However, the set $K_1$ only contains points with $x_3$ coordinate at least $\sqrt{2}$ (see (*) below), and all the points $(t,0,\sqrt{2})$ for $t\in[-1,1]$ are in $K_1$ (as they are at distance $\geq1$ of the four planes mentioned above). So $K_1$ is not a translate of $K$.
(*) To see why $K_1$ only contains points with $x_3$ coordinate at least $\sqrt{2}$, note that if $X:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;y>|x|\}$, then all points in $X$ at distance $\geq1$ of $\partial X$ have $y$ coordinate $\geq\sqrt{2}$; similarly, all points of $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times X$ at distance $>1$ of the planes $x_2=\pm x_3$ have $x_3$ coordinate at least $\sqrt{2}$.

Thanks! But the minimal value of $x_3$ on $K_1$ is not your $\sqrt{2}$, but rather is $x_* = \sqrt{5}/2 = 1.18..$ which is less than $\sqrt{2}$.  To see this,  form the sector obtained by intersecting the plane $x_2 = 0$ with your $K$.  You get a sector whose angle $\theta$ satisfies $tan(\theta/2) = 2/1$ and so $sin(\theta/2) = 1/x_$.  The point $P_ = (0,0, x_)$ is achieved by propagating the bounding rays of this sector in one unit.   (Your $\sqrt{2}$ comes from the  angle made by the orthogonal sector made   by intersecting   with the plane $x_1 = 0$.)  I believe $K_1 = P_ + K$.

It seems the point $(0,0,x_)$ is at distance $<1$ of the point $\left(0,\frac{x_}{2},\frac{x_}{2}\right)$, which is in the boundary of $K$. So $(0,0,x_)$ cannot be in $K_1$, right?

I also made an arithmetic error. Set $x_* = \sqrt{17}/4$.   The triangle with half angle
$\theta/2$ has, from your measurement specifications  $\tan(\theta/2) = 4/1$
whereas I had set the tangent to  $2/1$ by mistake.  The correct
triangle is thus a   $1:4: \sqrt{17}$ right triangle and $x_*$ comes from this.

Verification:  The eqns for $K_t$ can be obtained from the unit inward pointing normals of $K$. These yield the following  eqns for $K_t$:  $$a(y+z) \ge t$$
$$a(-y+ z) \ge t$$
$$b (x + 4z) \ge t$$
$$b (-x + 4z) \ge t$$
with $a = 1/\sqrt{2}$ and $b = 1/\sqrt{17}$.
Setting $x = y = 0$ and $t =1$ and  the $\ge$' to $=$' we see that
$(0,0,\sqrt{17}/4)$ is on the boundary of $K_1$.

Yes, it seemed strange to me that something like $\arctan(1/4)$ didn't appear somewhere in the argument. I didn't comment on that because the same idea still applies. E.g. the point $(0,0,\sqrt{17}/4)$ is at distance $<1$ of the point $(0,\sqrt{17}/8,\sqrt{17}/8)$, which is in the boundary of $K$ (In particular, I don't think it is in the boundary of $K_1$)

Maybe the problem with the verification is when you set $x=y=0$? It seems from the previous comment that you are only considering distances to the part of the boundary which is in the plane $x_2=0$

Conversations with friends  today led to a solution.
A generic 4-sided convex polyhedral cone in 3-space led to a counterexample.
To be specific, suppose  the 3-dimensional convex polyhedral cone
$K$ be defined by $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$
and $ax + by - cz = 0$ where $(a,b,c)$ is a unit vector with $a, b , c > 0$.
One verifies that the  four  faces of $K$ are all two-sided,  each being   bounded by two rays.
The polyhedron $K_t$,  $t > 0$ is defined by the
inequalities  $x \ge t, y \ge t,  z \ge t$
and $ax + by -cz \ge t$ since $x, y, z, ax + by -cz$
represent the distance from the four faces.
In particular the face $z = 1$ of $K_{1}$ is coordinatized
by $(x,y)$ and  is characterized by the inequalities
$x \ge 1, y \ge 1$ and $a x + by \ge 1 + c$.  One verifies that for
`most' choices of $a, b,c$  this particular  face of $K_1$
is three-sided.  For example, if $a = b = c  = 1/\sqrt{3}$
we have $a + b - c = 1/\sqrt{3} < 1 + 1/ \sqrt{3}$ which means that
the line $a x + by = 1+ c$ crosses into the interior $x > 1, y >1$ of this face of $K_1$,
We cannot translate a polyhedron all of whose faces are two-sided
and end up with one having a three-sided face.  So $K_1$
cannot be a  translate of $K$.

Does this imply that you think the solution I posted yesterday is not right? If there is some misunderstanding/you do not agree with my last comment that the point $(0,0,\sqrt{17}/4)$ is at distance $<1$ of the boundary (and so is $(0,0,x)$ for all $x<\sqrt{2}$, which is at distance $<1$ of the point $(0,x/2,x/2)$ in the boundary), we can discuss it further

You are right Saul.    I was wrong.   The distance from the origin to K_1 is root 2.   as you say.  Your sharper angle (90 degrees) made by the plane x=0 yields the furthest point.   Somehow I got the distance contributions from this angle and the other (y=0; shallower (arctan(1/4))  confused.
